# How to get yolov4 output in custom format

Tags: yolo, confusion-matrix, yolov5, yolov4

Current format I obtained through code below

```
'''-ext_output <data/test.txt> result.txt'''
```

is as follows.

```
'''Enter Image Path:  Detection layer: 139 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 150 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 161 - type = 28 
data/test/sb_0217_3_19010.jpg: Predicted in 6.802000 milli-seconds.
positioning: 99%    (left_x:  946   top_y:  396   width: 2221   height: 1281)'''
```

And I want to get this result.txt reported in this simple format:
class id - center_x - center_y - width - height

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

-save_labels
it creates separate files in yolo annotation format